# Creating a nested dictionary when a list item appears and matches in a string

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list of strings that I want to use to filter the text inside a nested dictionary. If one of the list items appear in the nested text, I would like to create a new list of dictionaries, with the list item as its parent key&value and the corresponding texts where the list item appears as nested list of dictionaries inside this parent key&value.

The list for filtering:

```
my_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse']
```

The current list of dictionaries looks something like this:

```
list_dicts = [{'id':1, 'text': 'This is a cat'}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'The man had a dog'}, 
               {'id': 3, 'text': 'There was a cat'}]
```

Desired output:

```
desired_output = [{'name': 'cat', 'matching_texts':[{'id': 1, 'text': 'This is a cat'}, 
                 {'id': 3,'There was a cat'}], {'name': 'dog', 'matching_texts':[{'id':2, 
                 'text': 'The man had a dog'}]}]
```

The best I can do for now is finding when an item of `my_list` appears in `list_dicts`. I thought about using `setdefault` method but I am unsure whether I am going in the right direction.
My code:

```
dic = {}
for d in list_dicts: 
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k == 'text':
            for i in my_list: 
                if i in v: 
                    dic.setdefault(i,v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using iteration:

```
main_list = []
for i in my_list:
    curr_dic = {"name": i, "matching_texts": []}
    for dic in list_dicts:
        if i in dic.get("text", ""):
            curr_dic["matching_texts"].append(dic)
    if curr_dic["matching_texts"]:
        main_list.append(curr_dic)
print(main_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using dict comprehension.

```
results = []
    for animal in my_list:
        temp = {"name": animal, "matching_texts": [element for element in list_dicts if animal in element.get("text")]} 
        if temp.get("matching_texts"): results.append(temp)
    print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my solution
my_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse']
list_dicts = [{'id':1, 'text': 'This is a cat'}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'The man had a dog'}, 
               {'id': 3, 'text': 'There was a cat'}]
aa=[]
a={'name':'','matching_texts':[]}
for x in my_list:
    for y in list_dicts:
        if y['text'].find(x)>=0:
            a['name']=x
            a['matching_texts'].append(y)
    if a['name']!='':aa.append(a)
    a={'name':'','matching_texts':[]}
print(aa)
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find the solutions here a bit hard to read. I would write something like:

```py
for current_word in my_list:
    matching_entries = [entry for entry in list_dicts if current_word in entry['text']]
    
    if matching_entries:
        output.append({'name': current_word, 'matching_texts': matching_entries})
```

The output is the same:

```
[
  {'name': 'cat', 'matching_texts': [
    {'id': 1, 'text': 'This is a cat'}, 
    {'id': 3, 'text': 'There was a cat'}
  ]}, 
  {'name': 'dog', 'matching_texts': [
    {'id': 2, 'text': 'The man had a dog'}
  ]}
]
```